# When to link frameworks/libraries on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, libraries

As the title says, when do we need to manually add a framework/library on Xcode?

When I say manually is by going to `AppTarget` -> `General` -> `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` -> `+` or the alternative `AppTarget` -> `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary with Libraries` -> `+`.

I created a new iOS project with two pods installed, so at this time the only framework listed on `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`/`Link Binary with Libraries` was the one generated by cocoapods.
Then I added `import AVFoundation` on a swift file, archive and everything succeeded.

The thing is that the list with the linked stuff never changed, neither the Frameworks group on the project navigator. So I wonder when should we use this?

Based on this I would assume that in old projects it is safe to remove everything from the Frameworks group which will also remove from the lists (of course leaving the Pods framework) should be fine. I did it, archived, exported, and everything went fine.
This is my assumption though but I would like to confirm it with someone else.

Perhaps this was necessary of old versions of Xcode, or with ObjC... I remember back in the day I had to this when using ObjC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link frameworks and libraries that are not provided by Apple in OS. As frameworks like "AVFoundation" are dynamic libraries provided in OS.

If you have made your own framework/library or using others then you have to link and embed them also in your xcode project.

From Xcode 5 LLVM and Clang provide option to auto-link libraries and Frameworks.By default the vaule is true.
That's why Apple system frameworks(default frameworks) do not have to be explicitly linked to Xcode projects.
See Options in Apple Clang-language- Modules in build settings.
Hope it Helps

Comment: This makes total sense, that was my assumption since the beginning but I wanted to confirm with someone else. Thank you very much!